# Pandas: Creating a new column based on if part of a string is anywhere in another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

Let's suppose we have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
0: 'ETERNITON',
1: 'CIELOON',
2: 'M.DIASBRANCOON',
3: 'IRBBRASIL REON',
4: '01/00 ATACADÃO S.A ON',
5: 'AMBEV S/A ON',
6: '01/00 RUMO S.A. ON',
7: 'COGNA ONON',
8: 'CURY S/A'}.items(), columns=['index', 'name']).set_index('index')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': {0: 'ALLIARON', 1: 'M.DIASBRANCOON', 2: 'AMBEVS/AON', 3: 'CIELOON',
  4: 'AESBRASILON', 5: 'BRASILAGROON', 6: 'IRBBRASILREON', 7: 'ATACADÃOS.AON', 8: 'ALPARGATASON',
  9: 'RUMOS.A.ON', 10: 'COGNAONON'},
 'yf_ticker': {0: 'AALR3.SA', 1: 'MDIA3.SA', 2: 'ABEV3.SA', 3: 'CIEL3.SA', 4: 'AESB3.SA',
  5: 'AGRO3.SA', 6: 'IRBR3.SA', 7: 'CRFB3.SA', 8: 'ALPA3.SA', 9: 'RAIL3.SA', 10: 'COGN3.SA'}})
```

I'd like to create a new column ('ticker') in df1 using the column 'yf_ticker' from df2. If a name/string in `df2['yf_ticker']` is in `df1['name']` (even if it is not an exactly match), then add the yf_ticker from df2 to that row in `df1['ticker']`. To make it clear, the expected output would be something like:

```
print(df1)
name                    ticker
ETERNITON               Missing or N/A or Nan
CIELOON                 CIEL3.SA
M.DIASBRANCOON          MDIA3.SA
IRBBRASIL REON          IRBR3.SA
01/00 ATACADÃO S.A ON   CRFB3.SA
AMBEV S/A ON            ABEV3.SA
01/00 RUMO S.A. ON      RAIL3.SA
COGNA ONON              COGN3.SA
CURY S/A                Missing or N/A or Nan
```

The solution I tried:

```
df1['name'] = df1['name'].str.replace(" ","")

for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df2.iloc[j,0] in df1.iloc[i,0]:
            df1.loc[i, 'ticker'] = df2.iloc[j,1]
```

Although it worked, it seems to me that such for loop for a larger dataset is inefficient. Is there a faster (or 'vectorized') way to do that?

Comment: Hi @Chris. I edited my question to add the solution I tried. Would you have a different approach?

Comment: Could u try left join or mapping?

Comment: problem is `"not an exactly match"` because standard functions may work with `"exactly match"`

Comment: for `"not an exactly match"` it may need to use `"fuzzy matching"` which frist may need to calculate `similarity` between all pairs `name` in both `DataFrame` and later get value with the biggest `similarity`. But all this may need external module for `"fuzzy matching"` and work in `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest fuzzy matching on the `name` columns, then get the `yf_ticker` from the matching row. Here is an example with python's built-in `difflib`:

```
import difflib

df1['yf_ticker'] = df1['name'].apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2['name'] == y[0], 'yf_ticker'].iloc[0] if (y := (difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2.name))) else None)
```

Output:

| index | name | yf_ticker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ETERNITON |  |
| 1 | CIELOON | CIEL3.SA |
| 2 | M.DIASBRANCOON | MDIA3.SA |
| 3 | IRBBRASIL REON | IRBR3.SA |
| 4 | 01/00 ATACADÃO S.A ON | CRFB3.SA |
| 5 | AMBEV S/A ON | ABEV3.SA |
| 6 | 01/00 RUMO S.A. ON | RAIL3.SA |
| 7 | COGNA ONON | COGN3.SA |
| 8 | CURY S/A |  |